# Removing a cookie from within a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to remove a Cookie (according to some criteria) from within a Chrome Extension.
According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html#method-remove) of `chrome.cookies.remove` it expects an object with the fields `url` (The URL associated with the cookie) and `name` (The name of the cookie to remove).

Now a [cookie](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html#type-Cookie) has the following fields: `name, value, domain, hostOnly, path, secure, httpOnly, session, expirationDate, storeId` but no **`url`**. How do I get the URL of a specific cookie so I can remove it?

For reference one of my cookies looks like this:

```
domain: ".google.com"
expirationDate: 1364393586
hostOnly: false
httpOnly: false
name: "PREF"
path: "/"
secure: false
session: false
storeId: "0"
value: "ID=8<snip>u"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some trial and error here's how I get the URL, this seems to work for everything (except perhaps `file://`)

```
function extrapolateUrlFromCookie(cookie) {
    var prefix = cookie.secure ? "https://" : "http://";
    if (cookie.domain.charAt(0) == ".")
        prefix += "www";

    return prefix + cookie.domain + cookie.path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed `http://www.google.com` as url and it worked. Maybe it just wants any url that matches `domain` pattern.

```
chrome.cookies.remove({url:"http://www.google.com", name: "PREF"});
```

(you also need to have domain permission for google.com)

Comment: Thanks this appears to work (although not on `httpOnly` cookies...)